# Can't reach apache document root from HOSTNAME.local on mavericks

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, webserver

I got some problems with reaching my local apache webserver from my MYHOSTNAME.local

There's no problem when I visit localhost, but when I visit MYHOSTNAME.local I get a white page.

It looks like some other process is listening my port 80.

I already tried to check who's listening the port 80:

[image]

But everything looks fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If something other than Apache was listening/responding to port 80 on your Mac, it should handle both localhost and myhostname.local addresses.

Get the IP address for your Mac, and then use that in the URL.  If that works, then you might have a DNS problem resolving myhostname.local.  Try to "ping" it from the Terminal.  Is it responding at all?  Does it map to the same IP as you used above?

If the ping test shows that DNS/IP seems fine, they other thing might be an issue with how Apache is configured.  I forget the exact syntax, but it can be configured to only respond to certain hostnames, I believe.  Add myhostname.local into the config.